# No Build Cache Found - Github Actions/NextJS App

Tags: caching, next.js, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I'm currently playing around with setting up a very basic CI pipeline (via Github Actions) for a NextJS app. Each time the workflow runs, it hits an error at the `npm run build` job and logs `warn  - No build cache found.`

So, I went to NextJS [documentation on this issue](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/ci-build-caching#github-actions), and added their suggested boilerplate code to my yml file.

However, each time running this workflow after adding the above code will result in the same `warn  - No build cache found.` error in the logs.

Here's my yml file I'm running within .github/workflows:

```
name: Build & Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: |
          ~/.npm
          ${{ github.workspace }}/.next/cache
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}-${{ hashFiles('**.[jt]s', '**.[jt]sx') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}-
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

Here's the error logs:

```
warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry

info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
info  - Using external babel configuration from /home/runner/work/Greenhouse-Hunter/Greenhouse-Hunter/.babelrc
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/index.js:3:1
Syntax error: "next/font" requires SWC although Babel is being used due to a custom babel config being present.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/babel-font-loader-conflict


> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried following the NextJS documentation on this issue, and I expected the `npm run build` step to pass, but it resulted in the same error as before (`warn  - No build cache found.`)

Comment: Your build is failing. You need to fix that. Apart from that, do you see any caches under Actions >> Management (left panel) >> Caches?

Comment: Yup, cache would get saved only if the entire workflow successfully completes.

Comment: If you want people to debug how the cache hit is missed, please fix your build first.